# jQuery slideDown then Up by itself in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have this code to slideDown a mobile menu when touched, but somehow only in Firefox, the div always back Up immediately by itself.

```
$('#burger').on('click touchstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery('#mobile-menu').is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery('body').css('position','relative');
        jQuery('.page').css({'overflow':'hidden','position':'fixed'});
        jQuery('#mobile-menu').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        jQuery('#mobile-menu').slideUp('slow');
        jQuery('.page').css({'overflow':'visible','position':'static'});
        jQuery('body').css('position','static');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try adding `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @tavnab Returning false automatically does that.

Comment: I suspect that both `click` and `touchstart` events are being sent. So one of them opens the menu, the other closes it. Are you sure you need both events?

Comment: @Barmar Ah right you are, I missed the `return false`. This may be a firefox bug

Comment: Removing the click did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than removing the `click` would removing `touchstart` work as well? This would let it work on non-touch devices (e.g. all-in-one tablets, Android STBs, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a Firefox bug; if that's the case and you need a not-so-elegant but working patch, you can try to stifle repeat events if they happen too quickly after this one.

```js
// when true, ignore the event
var stifleEvent = false;

$('#burger').on('click touchstart', function (e) {
  if (stifleEvent) {
    return false;
  }

  if (jQuery('#mobile-menu').is(":hidden")) {
    $('body').css('position','relative');
    $('.page').css({'overflow':'hidden','position':'fixed'});
    $('#mobile-menu').slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    $('#mobile-menu').slideUp('slow');
    $('.page').css({'overflow':'visible','position':'static'});
    $('body').css('position','static');
  }
  
  // ignore more of this event for the next 10ms
  stifleEvent = true;
  setTimeout(() => { stifleEvent = false; }, 10);
  
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div id="mobile-menu">
    Sliding Menu
  </div>
  <button id="burger" type="button">
    | | |
  </button>
</div>
```

Note that I removed the `e.preventDefault()` because returning false automatically calls this in JQuery, along with `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Removing the click so far the only trick.

Comment: You're right; the time between the `touchstart` and `click` could be as big as the user takes to lift their finger.